# How to remove these Timestamps from Vuetify Calendar?

Tags: vue.js, calendar, vuetify.js, vcalendar

[image: Visual Description]

I am trying to remove these timestamps but i am unable to so.

Comment: Remove am/pm rather?

Comment: @kissu i want no timestamp of am/pm. anytime.

Comment: How will you know when the event is happening? Having a calendar, focused on a single day with no time at all, looks kinda strange. Where would you see that you have an appointment at 8am to the doctor? You're maybe not looking for a calendar here. What you're looking for, is named [an `interval`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-calendar-daily/#props-interval-format) so you may maybe try to pass an empty string to `interval-format`. Looks weird to me still.

Comment: @kissu you are partially right , what i actually need is something on a calendar where i can just add events irrespective of time. All the events will have a order but not subjected to a particular time. and all of that in weekly calendar , this timestamp thing is in non-month type calendars. I hope i was understandable

Comment: Then, you don't really need a calendar. Create a simple grid (column with stripes) in CSS and manage the order of each event with an integer of each specific element (array of objects) to know which one is the first, second, third etc...

Comment: Thanks @kissu for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Just as kissu said, that's kinda wierd request. But, I guess you can just set the interval text as transparent.

```css
.v-calendar-daily__interval-text {
  color: transparent !important
}
```

What you're trying to build sounds more like a trello board to me, you can find a couple tutorials out there if you want to make your own.